# How do I make some files on my machine accessible via HTTP using Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, http

I did a wget on [the source](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache23) and built the apache binaries correctly.

- Now what do I need to do to get some documents accessible using HTTP (start some services?)? Also, do I need to group all the files I want to make accessible in some directory and make the directory and its contents accessible or can I just make the individual documents available?
- I will be providing these links to my colleagues and do not want them to be down, so need to make sure that the apache services are up automatically after a reboot. Does apache have some inbuilt support for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Now what do I need to do to get some documents accessible using HTTP (start some services?)?

After compiling, you need to **install** the files. Usually it's `make install` as *root*.

- However, most Linux distros already have Apache2 in their **repositories** – compiled, configured, etc. It's also **more convienent** than installing from source, since you get **updates** automagically.

  (Admittedly, you won't get the latest "beta" that way, but *do you need it* just to serve a few files? **Stick to the stable version**.)

> Also, do I need to group all the files I want to make accessible in some directory and make the directory and its contents accessible or can I just make the individual documents available?

You can only serve entire directories.

The default configuration of Apache2 usually points to **`/srv/http` or `/var/www`**, depending on the system.

- The default location for Apache2's config seems to be `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Look for a line that says "`DocumentRoot`".
- If using Debian's `apache2` package, you can change it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Next, **start** Apache2. Again, depending on the system, it may be one of the following:

- `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`
- `/etc/init.d/httpd start`
- `/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start`
- `/etc/rc.d/httpd start`
- `httpd`

Make sure you run the command as *root*.

> I will be providing these links to my colleagues and do not want them to be down, so need to make sure that the apache services are up automatically after a reboot. Does apache have some inbuilt support for this?

This depends on the operating system. On some Linux distros (Debian, Ubuntu), the initscript is added to the list of daemons to start automatically. On others you have to do it manually (in Arch, by editing `/etc/rc.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your question and I immediately thought of Dropbox. Check out http://www.dropbox.com/ and it just might be what you need. This way you will have http and web gui access to stored files from where-ever there is an internet connection. There are even shared folders you can create if you get your colleagues join too.

Not what you asked for, but could be a better, easier solution. :)

And no I don't work for them, just love the service!